# Java - receiving notifications using TCP Sockets

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

Is there a good way to create receiving notification to Client using TCP Socket (without Pushes)?

It's accepted to send a request and receive an answer from server. But if I need to receive some messages from server in any time without sending any request (only in the beginning for connecting)? Like in messengers.

I think it's not ok to send a request to the server every 5 secs (for example) to get an answer.

Comment: I think your only option here is push notifications.

Comment: [RFC 6455](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455) _The WebSocket Protocol_ is one option.

Comment: You can also send raw data over the socket creating your own protocol

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do that is to listen to websocket channels. I personally used [WebSocket Rails-Android](https://github.com/ararog/WebSocketRails-Android) because our server is written on rails, but you can easily find a library that fits your need.

In the library above you can also find a simple and clear explanation of how the listening thing works.

Comment: README.md says that WebSocket Rails-Android is built on top of AndroidAsync. Note that AndroidAsync does not perform the closing handshake which is required by RFC 6455 and has many open issues.